# Error in retrieving response from firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am a beginner to Firebase cloud Functions. My main motivation of using cloud functions is for authentication.

index.js (in functions folder)

```
    var admin = require("firebase-admin");
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const createuser = require('./funs/create_user');
    var serviceAccount = require('./funs/serviceAccount.json');

    admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
       databaseURL: "//Given by Firebase"
    });


    exports.createuser = functions.https.onRequest(createuser);
```

create_user.js

```
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    module.exports = function (req,res) {

       if(!req.body.phone)
       {
           return res.status(422).send({error: "Bad Input"});
       }

       const phone = String(req.body.phone).replace(/[^\d]/g,"");

       admin.auth().createUser({ uid: phone })
       .then((user) => res.send(user))
       .catch((err)=>res.status(422).send({error:err}));

       //return 1;

     }
```

When I call the function using Postman, I pass data to the cloud function as:

```
     {
         "phone": "1212121212"         
      }
```

I get response as "Bad Input" as specified inside of 
if statement.

On removal of the if condition i get this as my response

```
  {
    "error": {
    "code": "auth/invalid-uid",
    "message": "The uid must be a non-empty string with at most 128 
    characters."
  }
 }
```

[image: Postman]

Comment: How do you call this HTTPS function and how do you pass the data (i.e. phone number) to the body of the HTTP Request. What happens if you try to log req.body?

Comment: I call the function and pass the data using Postman web app. I have edited and attached the image link. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Cloud Function code is valid, I have successfully tested it in a Firebase project, using the [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library as follows, in an HTML page.

```
axios.post('https://us-central1-xxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/testPhoneNbr', {
    phone: '0471214365'
})
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The user is correctly created.

The problem is probably coming from the way you call the HTTPS Cloud Function.

Comment: Your right, I tested the function through Restlet Client web app this time. It worked. There could be a problem with the Postman API testing service The last sentence of your answer help me find alternatives. Thank you @Renaud Tarnec.

Answer (score 0):

Please change type="text" to type="JSON" in postman when hit the POST request